# Prevent reloading of angular component while refreshing page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I have Single Page Application website, written in angular 4+. I have so many components likes as FilterComponent, SideBarMenuComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, etc.

I want to prevent reloading of SideBarComponent to be initiated of ngOnInit when user refresh whole page. How can I do prevent ngOnInit method not to run for only SideBarMenuComponent so that whatever is user selected in side bar menu, it wont get removed.

Please let me know if you did not get understand in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

When user reload your SPA application then **your every component must reload**. 
You can store user's selected menu in local storage. So when user reload your app you can check previous selected menu

Comment: My application is totally based on rest api and have multiple api to provide list of side bar menu's like as different categories 
So I dont want to store selected values and then loop in through each list to display selected menu in updated response.

Comment: **Angular application  totally based on rest api** everybody know this. When user select a link you just will store this and have to check in your template loop. It's not big effect in your loop. But you can't prevent your onInit change after reload. If you don't want  to save local storage if can use fire base for this type data

Comment: `So I dont want to store selected values and then loop in through each list to display selected menu in updated response.` You dont need update your response for this

Comment: Yeah, thanks! even we do have another workaround, but I want to know, does angular provides a way to stop reloading of component when user refreshes whole page.

As far as i know, each component have its own state and angular preserves it.

Comment: I dont agree with you brother since google had introduced these frameworks so that we dont need to refresh whole data again and always try to enhance performance of our application by following different patterns. Earlier we used MVC to perform this task but as of now we use MVP, MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using Angular **pushState**:

https://angular.io/guide/router

As a matter of fact, as a coincidence, the link from the Angular documentation I included does exactly this too. If you go to the link above and refresh the page, the navigation on the left of the page stays the same, even if the page reloads.

Note that pushState requires server side support, meaning that the server needs to return the Angular app index.html instead of a 404. This is slightly more complex issue, but if, like me, you serve your Angular app from a Node.js backend (which is not an amazing idea), you can use this script:

```
const express = require('express');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const compression = require('compression');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const domain =  process.env.DOMAIN;

function ensureDomain(req, res, next) {
  if (!domain || req.hostname === domain) {
    // OK, continue
    return next();
  }

  // handle port numbers if you need non defaults
  res.redirect(`http://${domain}${req.url}`);
}

const app = express();

// at top of routing calls
app.all('*', ensureDomain);

app.use(compression());

// default to .html (you can omit the extension in the URL)
app.use(serveStatic(`${__dirname}/dist`, {
  'extensions': ['html'],
  etag: true
}));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running...');
});
```

Note the lines:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
});
```

which serve any request that hasn't been handled, with `index.html` (effectively instead of a 404).